# disappearing query strings for generated images on mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, query-string

I have an error appearing in my logs quite frequently: 
*The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter ....* 
I have never experienced this issue on my dev environment and was not able to reproduce it at all. Also it's important to note that not all users get this error only a select few.

This is the log extract:

> Exception: The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'level' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.FileResult RepPersonalSectorChart(Sectors, System.String, Int32)' in 'WebUI.Controllers.ReportsController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter. Parameter name: parameters
>   Type: System.ArgumentException
>   Machine: WIN-K4LOQAOUT74
>
> Request URL: http://example.com/Reports/RepPersonalSectorChart?CustomerSector=FinancialServices&userid=abcd-123&level=1
>   Is Authenticated: True
>   User: user@sample.com
>   User host address: 170.148.xxx.xxx
>   Request Method: GET
>   User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0
>   Referer: http://example.com/Customer
>   Script Name: /Reports/RepPersonalSectorChart

*the strange thing is that the logged request url HAS the parameter (level) that the controller is complaing about.*

This controller action is being called from a page, it generates a graph that is displayed as an image.

the markup on the page:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("RepPersonalSectorChart", "Reports", 
   new { CustomerSector = Model.Sector, userid = Model.CustId, level = 2 })" alt="@Model.CustName chart" style="width:90%;margin-left:5%;" />
```

and this is the controller action

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public FileResult RepPersonalSectorChart(Customer.Sectors CustomerSector, string userid, int level)
{ ....  return File(mschart, "image/jpeg"); }
```

What could be the problem here? How can the parameter be there and not be there at the same time?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like you have a quantum superposition problem ;) . Maybe get [glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/) or [Elmah](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Elmah.MVC/) to try narrow down the problem ( if you havnt already )